# In Ruby on Rails, render 'shared/score', :locals => { :score => @foo.score } will not pass in the local?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Maybe I missed something in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

It seems that to render a partial, we can use

```
render 'shared/score'
```

but the next section talks about locals

```
render :partial => 'bar', :locals => { :score => @foo.score }
```

But what about the first form?

```
render 'shared/score', :locals => { :score => @foo.score }
```

The line above will not pass in the locals, why?

It seems like it has to be

```
render :partial => 'shared/score', :locals => { :score => @foo.score }
```

but why is that?  (I am using Rails 3.0.6)

Comment: Does `render 'shared/score', { :score => @foo.score }` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually want:

```
render 'shared/score', { :score => @foo.score }
```

### Explanation

You can look at this for their source code on `render`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Rendering.html#method-i-render

If you see that if the first parameter is NOT a hash, it will default to that being the name of the partial, and pass the second paramater as locals.

The catch is that it wants the locals of in the 2nd paramater. `:locals => {:score => @foo.score}` may seem right at first, **but you actually want**: `{:score=> @foo.score}`.

The reason for this is that it sets the `:locals` option for the `_render_partial` method to the second paramater. So if you were to do it your way, it would actually look like:

```
:locals => {:locals => {:score=>@foo.score}}
```

Which doesn't make much sense.